# horizontally align elements inside div at the top part

Tags: html, css

I would like to align these elements horizontally:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="block">xxxxx</div>
  <div class="block">xxxx</div>
  <div class="block">xxx</div>
  <div class="block"><select multiple></select>
</div>

.row {
  width: 100%;
  /*margin: 0 auto;*/
    text-align: center;
}
.block {
  width: 100px;
  /*float: left;*/
    display: inline-block;
    zoom: 1;
}
```

However the output that I see with the previous code is that:

```
               divS
               divS
div1 div2 div3 divS
```

I want to find a way to align the first three divs with the top part of the select and not with the bottom part.

```
div1 div2 div3 divS
               divS
               divS
```

Is it possible?

Comment: @SreenathPG I updated the question.

Comment: Yes, I have posted answer. Please check that and let me know if it helped you or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add  `vertical-align:top` to **.block** class. Please let me know if you wanted this.

```
.block {
  width: 100px;
  /*float: left;*/
    display: inline-block;
    zoom: 1;
    vertical-align:top;
}
.row {
  width: 100%;
  /*margin: 0 auto;*/
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: perfect I wanted that!